# Flask fails with "Error: While importing 'X', an ImportError was raised", but does not display the error. How to find the source of the error?

Tags: python, flask, python-import

When starting a Flask app with:

```sh
$ flask run
```

I received the error:

> ```
> Error: While importing 'wsgi', an ImportError was raised.
>
> Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...`
> ...
> ```

However, there is no stack trace or other information provided. What is the best way to get the `ImportError` stack trace?

Comment: Did you try `import wsgi` at the interpreter prompt?

Comment: I mean, the interpreter prompt that you get by running Python at the command line. If a program is telling me that it couldn't import a module within its framework, the first are-the-lights-on check is whether the module can be imported in new code from scratch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Import the Flask app at the Python interpreter prompt

To see the `ImportError` stack trace, open a Python interpreter prompt and import the module that loads the Flask app (usually app.py or wsgi.py). If applicable, be sure that your virtual environment is activated.

```sh
$ python
>>> from my_app_folder import app
```

### Set the `FLASK_APP` environment variable

If you can import the Flask app module using the Python interpreter without error, try setting the `FLASK_APP` environment variable to point to the Flask app module.

```sh
$ FLASK_APP='my_app_folder/app' FLASK_ENV=development flask run
```

Answer (score 3):

This error can be caused if Flask is unable to import any libraries(in my case it was Flask_restful)

This is the workaround I found to find the missing libraries:-

I found which library was missing by just running the Flask App file (wsgi.py) directly with python

```
    python wsgi.py
```

which gave an Importerror listing the missing libraries

after finding the missing libraries, simply install libraries using pip, for me Flask_restful was missing so I installed Flask_restful
.
After installing missing libraries simply run the flask app using

```
    flask run
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I would add to [Christopher Peisert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164465/christopher-peisert)'s answer is the option that gave me the error messages that I was searching for:

```
(venv) ~/example_flask_app/$ python
>>> import app
```

Or in my case

```
>>> import microblog
```