# flask db commands: ImportError

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I am new to flask and python (I have background in other languages and front-end dev).

Currently trying to update my sqlite3 database with additional columns. My app is throwing me a "no column found" error. From here, I have read about the need to refresh the sqlite3 database. I discovered that Flask Migrate and Alembic are part of these solutions and I need to use Flask Migrate to update the sqlite3 database.

I have Alembic and Flask Migrate in the `/Users/xxxx/code/Platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages` folder

The app tree is

```
/Platform
|-__init__.py
|-models.py
|-platform.sqlite3
templates
    |--index.html
venv
|-bin
|-include
|-library
|-pyvenv.cfg
static
|-css
|-js
alembic
admin
|-_pycache_
|-static
|-templates
|__init.py__
|admin.py
__pycache__
requirements.txt
README.md
```

**init.py** file:

```
from crypt import methods
from enum import unique
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, session, request
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from sqlalchemy import over
from models import db, Users
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_manager, login_user, LoginManager, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from forms import UserForm, LoginForm, Survey
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

# Blueprints
from admin import admin
```

models.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from datetime import datetime

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

/admin/**init.py**_ file:

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, redirect, session
from flask.templating import render_template
from models import db, Users
from forms import UserForm
from sqlalchemy import func, join
from flask_login import login_required, logout_user, current_user
from collections import namedtuple
```

I am trying to update the sqlite3 database in my flask app.

I continuously get an error (`"Error: While importing 'Platform.wsgi', an ImportError was raised."`) when trying to run `'flask db migrate'` to refresh the sqlite3 database so the added columns will show up in my app.

On further inspection, I have tried running different commands with `'flask db'` in terminal on mac.

Running `'flask db'` shows me a list of commands: (branches, current, downgrade, edit, heads, etc).

```
flask db
Usage: flask db [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Perform database migrations.

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  branches        Show current branch points
  current         Display the current revision for each database.
  downgrade       Revert to a previous version
  edit            Edit a revision file
  heads           Show current available heads in the script directory
  history         List changeset scripts in chronological order.
  init            Creates a new migration repository.
  list-templates  List available templates.
  merge           Merge two revisions together, creating a new revision file
  migrate         Autogenerate a new revision file (Alias for 'revision...
  revision        Create a new revision file.
  show            Show the revision denoted by the given symbol.
  stamp           'stamp' the revision table with the given revision;...
  upgrade         Upgrade to a later version
```

The issue is anytime I try and run a `'flask db init'` or `'flask db migrate'` to update my sqlite3 db, I get this error:

`"Error: While importing 'Platform.wsgi', an ImportError was raised."`

I am not sure how to solve for this wsgi error that continues to show up. It seems once I solve for this, I will be able to run flask db migrate to update my database and get the new data and columns to show up.

Really appreciate the time to read this and offer any advice. I've been stuck on this for the past 4 days, reading and troubleshooting all the various ideas I have found here on StackOverflow, but no luck.

This is my first post here.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask fails with "Error: While importing 'X', an ImportError was raised", but does not display the error. How to find the source of the error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70118990/flask-fails-with-error-while-importing-x-an-importerror-was-raised-but-do)

Comment: That does not answer my question. When I try to run from xxxxx import app it doesnt find the app. The error I see in my terminal is different than the error from the page you linked. I am seeing "Error: While importing 'Platform.wsgi', an ImportError was raised." -- which seems to me that it cant import Platform.wsgi but that is the name of the project and it is able to run.

Comment: What is `Platform.wsgi`? I don't see it defined anywhere in all the code snippets that you included in your question. I assume this is set in your`FLASK_APP` variable? If not why is this being imported?

Comment: Thank you Miguel. Platform is the name of the folder with the app. I am assuming there is some issue where its not recognizing Platform as some wsgi file? From here, I can't sort this out and can't get to running flask migrate commands. So I need to sort out why its looking for a wsgi file related to the project name Platform? Ive googled around and searched here and read some alternate things, but nothing directly correlated to my exact issue. A bit lost. Thank you for reading and helping!